# refresh the state and controller when reloading the page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm having this annoying issue, when i refresh my page, it's not reloading the controller or the state. I'm using ui-router and Angularjs. I don't understand because only one page is having this trouble. 
Here is my app.js:
(the page which having this issue this app.organization):

```
var route = angular.module('route', ["ui.router","starter"])
route.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/app")

    $stateProvider


        .state('app',{
            abstract:false,
            url:"/app",
            templateUrl: "views/header.html",
            controller:"homeCtrl"

        })
        .state('app.organization', {
            url: "/organization:id",
            templateUrl: "views/organization.html",
            controller:"homeCtrl"
        })
        .state('app.usersingle',{
        url:"/user:id?page:iterate",
        templateUrl: "views/single_user.html",
        controller:"userCtrl"
        })
        .state('app.ticket',{
            url:"/ticket:id/author:myid",
            templateUrl: "views/ticket.html",
            controller:"ticketCtrl"
        })
    });
```

and in my controller i declare this as :

```
 .controller('homeCtrl',['$state','$stateParams','$scope','dropdown','userdisplay','displayfilter','$q','$http',

        function ($state,$stateParams,$scope,dropdown,userdisplay,displayfilter,$q,$http) {

// doing request etc...

}])
```

I really don't know wher the problem came from and how can i resolve it any help would be really appreciate.

Comment: And by refresh you mean (CTRL+R (F5) refresh) or programmaticaly trying to reload the same state?

Comment: when i say refresh i mean yeah (CTRL+R(F5))

Answer (score 0):

Its because of our state definition is incorrect for `app.organization`.
Change it as below:

```
    .state('app.organization', {
        url: "/organization/:id",
        templateUrl: "views/organization.html",
        controller:"homeCtrl"
    });
```

On further looking I think this issues is other states as well. Correct them and it should work. Refer this for details: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters

Comment: On this point you are right but it's not resolve my issue. I have still the problem of refresh not working

Comment: my code is something like that: https://plnkr.co/edit/C2XsdzRdzJ5gup7RAtXY?p=preview, i can't made a working plunker because i made many request and many things in controller and useless to show you a bench of code